# Checkmark over a flexbox Div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is made in flexbox, now I want to overlay a check mark that covers the entire div but the content still is visable.

Now I googled around and all the solutions use position(absolute) but the problem is my page has scrolling, so my overlay goes with scrolling when it needs to be stationary.

```
  <div className="card z-depth-3">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div className="location">Home</div>
      <img className="logo" src="" height="50" width="50" ></img>
      <div className="name">Name</div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: In your code example, which div does the checkmark image need to overlay? Is `div.overlay` the checkmark image? Could you explain further about the page having scrolling but the overlay needs to be stationary - not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The checkmark should fill the entire parent container("card") but all the other content should still be visible. What I mean is when I start scrolling down the check mark leaves the "card" container since it is outside of the dom.

Comment: add position:relative to parent container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to apply `position: relative` to `.card` to make the `.overlay` position relatively to its parent (which is `.card`) that does have a `position: absolute` applied.

Some points though :

- there is no any `HTML` attribute called `className`, it's `class`.
- The `img` tag is self-closing meaning it doesn't have a closing tag.

So, here's a demo :

> the below example will have two ".card" one have a long height and the other without specifying any height so you should see that the checkmark stays in place even when having to scroll.

```css
.card {
  position: relative; /** allow the ".overlay" to be positionned relative to ".card" **/
  margin: 15px 0;
}

/** the ".card" having some scrolling **/
.card.has-height {
  height: 180vh; /** just to have some scrolling, remove this or replace it with your desired value **/
}

.overlay {
  display: flex; /** to center the checkmark both vertically and horizontally with two simple rules **/
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center; /** center the checkmark horizontally **/
  align-items: center; /** center the checkmark vertically **/
  background-color: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6); /** transparent black background to see the effect when scrolling **/
}

/** some styling for the checkmark **/
.overlay .fa {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- I used "Font Awesome" to render a checkmark -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" />

<!-- this ".card" won't have any scrolling (acting like a real card) -->

<div class="card z-depth-3">
  <div class="overlay"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
  <div class="location">Home</div>
  <!-- for demo purposes I used a placeholder image from "https://placeholder.com" -->
  <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" height="50" width="50">
  <div class="name">Name</div>
</div>

<!-- this ".card" will have some scrolling to show the placement of the checkmark when scrolling -->

<div class="card has-height z-depth-3">
  <div class="overlay"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
  <div class="location">Home</div>
  <!-- for demo purposes I used a placeholder image from "https://placeholder.com"  -->
  <img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" height="50" width="50">
  <div class="name">Name</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *there is no any HTML attribute called className* --> it's a React code and it's valid

Comment: He didn't add the `React` tag. Also, it's valid for `React` not standard `HTML`.

Comment: I am not the asker and we don't need to add React tag if it's not relevant to the question and if the issue is only related to CSS. It's like someone writing SASS code and is having a pure CSS solution.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah I know you're not the OP my fault (didn't read the username so asleep). From someone, who never had any contact with `React`, perspective I assume it's `HTML` from the first glance unless the OP mentions it.